# Rounding cutoffs of decision trees

Tags: scikit-learn, tree, classification

I'm using the DecisionTreeClassifier from sci-kit learn and obtain the following tree:

```
    if 'Salary' <= 1216.2154586:
        if 'Age' <= 25.55487:
            leaf 1
        else: 
            leaf 2
    else:
        leaf 3
```

I would like to know if there is a way for the splitting algorithm to cut with a rounding criteria:

```
    if 'Salary' <= 1200:
        if 'Age' <= 25:
            leaf 1
        else: 
            leaf 2
    else:
        leaf 3
```

Answer (score 1):

A small clarification - it's the splitting algorithm that makes the cuts, the pruning part comes afterwards and it is only used to reduce the depth of the tree by removing some nodes.

Anyway, the splitting algorithm will not be able to do what you want automatically, as it will always take the midpoint of the best split interval (meaning that, when it finds between which two values it has to split, it will keep the middle point as a threshold).

However you can probably do so manually with something like this:

```
estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(...)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

for elem in estimator.tree_.threshold:
    elem = round(elem,0)
```

You should also be able to do some more complex rounding rule if you want, based on which feature you have (given you don't have too many).
For example, you can loop over `estimator.tree_` and round the `estimator.tree_.threshold` based on the value of `estimator.tree_.feature`, given that you probably want different type of rounding for salary and age.

HOWEVER - let me point out that this might affect negatively the performance of your estimator, as you will not be splitting in the optimal points anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I'll edit my question.